# I want to add a profilePicture and save it on NEDB

Tags: javascript, html

Im have this code right know but cant save the picture. The URL is changed when i log out and in again.
Can i do something with this code or is it another code i can use?
I have heard that i may can convert to Base64 string but i dont know how i do that or where.

The URL is : blob:http://127.0.0.1:5502/591a0f75-2ed9-4011-b59a-7c2ea668e534

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', function() {
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
            var img = document.querySelector(".myImg"); // $('img')[0]
            img.onload = imageIsLoaded;
            img.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]); // set src to blob url
        }
    });
});

});
```

```
  <div class="Profil__Picture-Button">
     <img src="./img/LogoFinderV21.png" alt="your image" class="Profile__Profile-Picture myImg">
     <input type="file" />
  </div>
```

```
app.post('/login', async(req, res) => {
    user = await collectionsNEDB.users.find({})
    let matchedUser
    for (let i = 0; i < user.length; i++) {
        console.log(user[i].username)
        console.log(user[i]._id)
        if (req.body.username == user[i].username && req.body.password == user[i].password) {
            matchedUser = user[i]
            break
        }
    }
    if (matchedUser) {
        const payload = { userId: matchedUser._id }
        const token = jwt.sign(payload, "hej", { expiresIn: '1s' })
        res.json({ token, userId: matchedUser._id, user })
    } else {
        res.status(403).json({ error: 'Invalid Credentials' })
    }
})

app.get('/secured', auth, (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: `${req.user}` })
})
```

The code that i add the image to NEDB :

```
async function updateUser(age, city, gender, games, discord, steam, origin, image) {
    const id = localStorage.getItem("userId")
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/users/' + id, {
        method: 'PATCH',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            age: age,
            city: city,
            gender: gender,
            games: games,
            usernameDiscord: discord,
            usernameSteam: steam,
            usernameOrigin: origin,
            image: image
        })
    })
    console.log(response)
    const data = await response.json()
    console.log(data)
}

function updateUsersIndex() {
    let updateProfileBtn = document.querySelector(".Profile-Right__Update")
    console.log(updateProfileBtn)
    updateProfileBtn.addEventListener("click", async(event) => {
        console.log("hej")
        event.preventDefault()
        const age = document.querySelector(".Age__Input").value
        const city = document.querySelector(".City__Input").value
        const gender = document.querySelector(".Gender__Input").value
        const discord = document.querySelector(".Discord__Input").value
        const steam = document.querySelector(".Steam__Input").value
        const origin = document.querySelector(".Origin__Input").value
        const games = document.querySelector(".Profile-Right__Select-Game").value
        const image = document.querySelector(".Profile__Profile-Picture").src
        const hidden = document.querySelector(".hidden")
        const updateUsers = await updateUser(age, city, gender, games, discord, steam, origin, image)
        window.location.reload(true)
        toggling([".Profile__Wrappe"])
    })
}
updateUsersIndex()
```

Comment: Can you post your server code? Why does the URL change? Where do you log in and out?

Comment: i have updated the code. I Thhink it becouse something about its saved on de window and when i change window the URL blob i changed